# PowerShell script to copy files and iterate them depending on name and timestamp

Tags: powershell, timestamp

Let me start by saying, I really don't know powershell. I am an pharma process automation engineer so my experience is programming PLCs and HMI design. I have written all sorts of languages but I am by no means a programmer. But this is where we find ourselves, trying to write code for a solution that is needed and no one else knows how to do it.

I have two folders. One with unrestricted NTFS permissions, and one with read only permissions for everyone except local admins group. I need to copy files from the unrestricted folder to the one with read only permissions. I was going to use robocopy but I need to increment the file names if they exist in the destination with the same name but (different) time stamp and not copy it if the timestamp is the same. Robocopy can't do that.

I found a sample script that works for the incrementation, but does not consider the time stamp, the problem is that I am using task scheduler to trigger this script every time a PDF is printed. The script moves the printed PDF from one folder to the other, but the current script will keep making new copies with incremented numbering every time it is run. That won't work for what I need. I don't know powershell well enough to figure out how to have it consider the timestamp and increment files with different timestamps and ignore those with the same.

Here is the script I have so far:

```
function fcopy ($SourceDir,$DestinationDir)
{
    Get-ChildItem $SourceDir -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | ForEach-Object ($_) {
        $SourceFile = $_.FullName
        $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_
        if (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
            $i = 0
            while (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
                $i += 1
                $DestinationFile = $DestinationDir + $_.basename + $i + $_.extension
            }
        } else {
            Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Verbose -Force
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Verbose -Force
    }
}
fcopy -SourceDir "C:\SoloVPE\UV1325A_Reports\" -DestinationDir "C:\UV1325A_Reports_Share\"
```

Comment: Computers and software are fantastic tools, but they will only do what they are told to do. Learning to use any tool as designed is critical for success. If you need to work with different attributes, you have to tell PS to use that. Basename has nothing to do with finding timestamps. There are specific properties for timestamps available. Get the list of properties on the file and choose the one you want to leverage. ***Get-ChildItem 'D:\Temp' | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Member*** You should leverage a comparison for what you are after. So, additional If/Then logic or the like is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that the script I currently have does not consider timestamp. Maybe I wasn't as clear as I could have been.

Comment: No worries. This was just a comment to inform you where you should be focusing your efforts.